# Limiting the adding of rows in a form to a certain number

Tags: angular6, angular-forms, angular-material-6

I am working on adding and deleting a set of fields in a row, i am able to do this via the following code,
but will have to limit it to a certain number, how would i be able to do that? Thanks in advance
The below is the code. 
I am using an array and then using add and delete function for
Component File
`

```
 get formArr(){
    return this.finDetailsForm.get('itemRows') as FormArray;
 }

 initItemRows(){
    return this.fb.group({
        acc_name: '',
        inv_amt: '',
        v_inv_date: '',
    });
 }

 addNewRow(){
    this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
 }

 deleteRow(index: number) {
    this.formArr.removeAt(index);
 }
```

Attaching an image below of it 
[image: add and del row in form]

Comment: You can create a variable for counting. Then you can decide that inside `addNewRow` function. can add your DOM elements. That will be easier for others

Comment: Use the `FormArray.length` property to conditionally disable or exclude your add buttons in the GUI or to prevent adding the rows in the function.

Answer (score 0):

you can count length of array before push element.

```
 addNewRow(){
  if(this.formArr.lenght < 5){
    this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions:

Update your component function as below:

```js
class YourComponent {
private static MAX_ITEMS = << a number >>;
// ... constructor and rest ...

addNewRow(): void {
    if (this.formArr.length < YourComponent.MAX_ITEMS) {
        return;
    }

    this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
}
```

or you simply hide the button "+" when you reached the maximum item you want:

`your-component.ts`

```
get maxItemsReached(): boolean {
   return this.formArr.length >= YourComponent.MAX_ITEMS;
}
```

`your-component.html`

```html
<input type="button" *ngIf="!maxItemsReached">Add</input>
```